# Python Pandas: Json to Customized Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the my json file using python pandas as I show in the photo. But my code doesn't show the way I want. How can I do this?

What I want to do:

[image]

My code:

```html
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd


with urllib.request.urlopen("myurl.json [for privacy same as below json code]") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df)
```

My Json file:

```html
{
  "Akpınar Ges" : {
    "Bahri Kaşarcı" : 23,
    "Nuri esen" : 1,
    "selahattin dinç" : 2
  },
  "Endora Eryaman" : {
    "medine gamze erkek" : 27
  },
  "Gölbaşı Ges" : {
    "MOLLA AHMET ŞAHİN " : 10,
    "Mehmet ŞAHİN " : 10,
    "muhammed güngör " : 10
  }
}
```

Comment: `df.stack().swaplevel()`

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thank you, it's worked. (Teşekkür ederim ;) )